# Alternative to .includes()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to develop a method to match words in array (fItems) with words from a string which has been converted into an Array (stringArray). The code I have below works most the time, but the trouble is that 'includes()' searches for patterns, rather than matching the whole word.

As an example. it gets confused if I'm looking for 'wall', and it returns 'wallet'. Also, I want the input to be flexible. So for instance, if glass is inputted, the item 'glass shard' is still returnable.

Is there are more precise way to match exact words?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < db.items.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
   if (db.items[i].name.includes(stringArray[j])) {
    fItems.push(db.items[i]);
   };
  }
 };
```

Comment: put the db data

Comment: You mean just an straight comparison? `db.items[i].name == stringArray[j]`

Comment: So you're trying to get the *intersection* of the two arrays. Look that up, you'll find plenty of solutions on SO.

Comment: No, not a straight comparison. I want the input to be flexible. So for instance, if glass is inputted, the item 'glass shard' is still returnable.

Comment: This sounds like pattern matching on strings, use a regular expression instead. Its faster and easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*from comment*

> No, not a straight comparison. I want the input to be flexible. So for instance, if glass is inputted, the item 'glass shard' is still returnable.

It sounds like what you are really after is pattern matching in a string. A regular expression would be the best thing to use for that as this is why they were created (*pattern matching with the option of replacement*).

```
let str = 'The glass shard';
let search = 'glass';
let isMatch = new RegExp('\\b'+search+'\\b', 'i').test(str); // i is case insensitive

// If you use unicode characters then this might be a better expression
// thank you @Touffy
let isMatch = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)'+search, 'i').test(str); // i is case insensitive
```

In the code above `\b` is used to denote a word boundary so `glass` is a match but `glassware` would not be matched. `i` is used to specify case insensitive.

Also to test your expressions online before you place them in your code you can use this site https://regex101.com/, I use this all the time to verify the expressions I build are accurate.

Comment: since OP was using `Array.includes`, he may have the option to specify Unicode-safe regexes. Otherwise, don't forget that `\b` will match the empty space between `\w` and any non-ASCII character, including letters commonly used in English such as "é".

Comment: Good answer, expect that OP seems to be using ES2015 (`let`) and the code in the answer is ES5.

Comment: @Igor - and unfortunately, not easy to overcome. `\S` sometimes works as a good-enough replacement for `\w`.

Comment: Thank you. I have to admit, I go a little pale when someone mentions regex. I guess it's time to find a way to learn them. But they do seem to make life easier. I will try to learn to use them.

Comment: @Cuckoo - I added one update to the last expression for if you happen to be searching unicode text. Regular expressions do make life simpler if you deal with a lot of text, I use them regularly (no pun intended) and once you start using them you get the hang of them fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to try and implement it.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how I implement regex with my code. Could you give me an example please? Where the search string is array1 = ["a","wall"]; and the database in array2 = ["a glass shard", "a wallet", "a stone wall"]; - so that it returns 'a stone wall'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `split` and `indexOf` methods instead of it. After split, you can check it with indexOf.

> From Comment: As Pavlo said, also you can use `includes`, instead of `indexOf` method.

```
for (let i = 0; i < db.items.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
            if (db.items[i].name.split(' ').indexOf(stringArray[j])!==-1) {
                fItems.push(db.items[i]);
            };
        }
    };
```

Comment: You can use `Array#includes` instead of `Array#indexOf`, assuming the code is ES2016.

Comment: @Pavlo thanks for your suggestion. I have just learned it thanks of you :)

Comment: I used includes in the original code I posted, the trouble is it looks for matching patterns, not whole words.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dot function and use it just like es6 includes() in es5 as below :

```
String.prototype.includes = function (str) {
 return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
}
```

Following is the string

```
var myString = 'this is my string';
```

Checking the match as following:

```
console.log(myString.includes('string')); // true
console.log(myString.includes('street')); //false
```

Now you can add this for ES5 using same *indexOf* in *includes* way